# Execution of function after 2 s

Tags: javascript, jquery

Below I have written a function for a hover element. I want this function is performed only when the mouse is on that part of 2 or more seconds. When they will be less or not at all this is not to make.

Below the code I wrote:

```
$(function(){
    $('section.zespol_list ul li a').hover(function(){
        $(this).next().fadeIn(1000);
    },
    function(){
        $(this).next().fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 6):

You can use `setTimeout` to delay the execution and within that time if mouseout is fired clear the timer using `clearTimeout`.

```
$(function(){
    var timeOutId;
    $('section.zespol_list ul li a').hover(function(){
        timeOutId= setTimeout(function(){ 
             $(this).next().fadeIn(1000)
        ), 2000);
    },
    function(){
        clearTimeout(timeOutId);
        $(this).next().fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1):

Use `setTimeout()` and clear it with `clearTimeout()`

```
var timer;
$(function(){
    $('section.zespol_list ul li a').hover(function(){
        timer = setTimeout(function() {
            $(this).next().fadeIn(1000); 
        }, 2000);
    },
    function(){
        clearTimeout(timer);
        $(this).next().fadeOut(1000);
    });
});
```

Comment: Just wanted to solve it but it does not work at all. Below I attach the code to the web version:

http://tinyurl.com/7j9934v

This test may be in the pictures arranged in a square boards.

Comment: @Pietrov that's not my fault, there's an error: `Uncaught TypeError: Object [object Object] has no method 'slideViewerPro'`

Comment: Ok I removed the problem and did not work on the code. Could other scripts affect his work?

Comment: @Pietrov try $(this).parent().next() instead of what you'Re using now

Comment: Ok the code began to work, but somehow strangely. After those two seconds to appear div.name which is located in the element if the <a>. And here's the part you are gone.

Answer (score 0):

Actually there is a plug-in called [HoverIntent](http://cherne.net/brian/resources/jquery.hoverIntent.html). I haven't used it personally, but seems like it would solve your problem

Comment: That won't help as it doesn't get canceled